# Local copy runs but copied to webserver causes errors with TypeError not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I've built a js/html page to capture images from a webcam and it runs on local but when loading through web hosted it says one of my functions is not a function.

Already hosted on local and it works there. Tried using different function names.

```
        <div class="booth">
            <video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
            <a href="#" id="capture" class="booth-capture-button">Take photo</a>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
            <img id="photo" src="#" alt="Photo">
        </div>

        <script src="js/photo.js"></script>
```

```js
(function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        photo = document.getElementById('photo'),
        vendorURrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false
    }, function(stream) {
        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, function(error) {
        // An error occured
        // error.code
    });

    document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click', function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
        photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
});
})();
```

Expected to capture image and place it in picture box but web hosted does not capture at all. Uncaught TypeError: Navigator.getMedia is not a function at line 13 at line 28

Comment: You don't have code checking if navigator.getMedia is null before invoking it. Maybe your code doesn't have permissions to that object from a remote server like it does from localhost? The API says it needs a permission.

Comment: Also, note that getUserMedia is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia